# Styling CSS Border with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the color of a border by cycling through an array of colors using JavaScript. I understand how to manipulate most CSS properties using JavaScript but am having trouble manipulating a CSS property that has multiply values (i.e. border: #px, solid, color)

Here is my JS:

```
  var self = document.getElementById("self");
  var colorArray = ["red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "orange", "cyan", "gray"];
  var colorIndex = 0;

  function changeColor () {
    self.style.border = 6px solid colorArray[colorIndex];
    colorIndex++;

    if (colorIndex >= colorArray.length) {
      colorIndex = 0;
    }
  }

setInterval(changeColor,1000);
```

There's a problem with the self.style.border = ... line. What's my problem?

Comment: Try changing to `self.style.border = '6px solid'+ colorArray[colorIndex];`

Comment: The problem is that `6px solid colorArray[colorIndex]` is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: Right. What would be the valid JS version of that line? '6x solid' + colorArray[colorIndex] does not seem to work.

Comment: Missing a space -> `'6px solid ' + colorArray[colorIndex]`

Comment: @adeno is right. Now it is working perfectly.

Comment: try Daniel suggestion. but put a space between solid and calorArray concat.
 self.style.border = '6px solid '+ colorArray[colorIndex];

Answer (score 1):

Daniel was almost right. Don't forget your spacing between property values in your css declaration. See below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var self = document.getElementById("self");
var colorArray = ["red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "orange", "cyan", "gray"];
var colorIndex = 0;

function changeColor () {
    self.style.border = "6px solid " + colorArray[colorIndex];
    colorIndex++;

    if (colorIndex >= colorArray.length) {
        colorIndex = 0;
    }
}

setInterval(changeColor,1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is change the color of the border, there is no need to use the `border` shorthand to change all aspects of the border:

```
self.style.borderColor = colorArray[colorIndex];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should change, since except color other are string value in your case:

**self.style.border = "6px solid " + colorArray[colorIndex];**

Complete code:

```
var self = document.getElementById("self");
var colorArray = ["red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "orange", "cyan", "gray"];
var colorIndex = 0;

function changeColor () {
self.style.border = "6px solid " + colorArray[colorIndex];
colorIndex++;

if (colorIndex >= colorArray.length) {
  colorIndex = 0;
}
}


setInterval(changeColor,1000);
```

Regards,
Ashok

Comment: Wow. While providing solution to you, I found three answers were added in the meantime. My answer is almost same as user3677980. thought to update you.